# Google spreadsheet Vlookup row parameter always increment after delete response form

Tags: google-sheets, auto-increment, gs-vlookup

I have a problem when i delete all rows from response sheet, then my Vlookup formula always auto-increment at row section. 
Ex : I have

```
=VLOOKUP(C1,'Form Responses 2'!$B$2:$C$37,2,FALSE)
```

After delete responses (because I want to make it start at row 2 again) it gave me:

```
=VLOOKUP(C1,'Form Responses 2'!$B$3:$C$37,2,FALSE)
```

The row change from $B$2 into $B$3 automatically. Any suggestion?

PS : I have to reset all responses and sheet each week. I just can't check and edit all the formulas for each table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to turn the VLOOKUP into an array formula and 'hide' in in the header row (row1)

={"SOME TITLE FOR THE HEADER"; ARRAYFORMULA (IF (LEN (C2:C), VLOOKUP(C2:C,'Form Responses 2'!$B$2:$C$37,2,FALSE),))